# how to input percentage using a dot for example 8.2 in C#

Tags: c#

```
Console.Write("Enter employee name: ");
string name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter his/her yearly salary: ");
double oldYearlySalary = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter an Increase percentage(7.5): ");
double increasePercentage = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

double newYearlySalary = oldYearlySalary + oldYearlySalary * increasePercentage;
double oldMonthlySalary = oldYearlySalary / 12;
double newMonthlySalary = oldMonthlySalary + oldMonthlySalary * increasePercentage;
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Employee Details: ");
Console.WriteLine($"Employee name: {name}");
Console.WriteLine($"Old yearly salary: {oldYearlySalary:C}");
Console.WriteLine($"Old month salary: {oldMonthlySalary:C}");
Console.WriteLine($"Increase percentage: {increasePercentage.ToString("0,00%")}");
Console.WriteLine($"New yearly salary: {newYearlySalary:C}");
Console.WriteLine($"New monthly salary: {newMonthlySalary:C}");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and explain what this code does or doesn't do, and what you have tried to fix it. Is the issue that `Convert.ToDouble()` throws an exception when you enter "8.2"? Then read and research that exception.

Answer (score -1):

Use double.TryParse:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (double.TryParse(input, out double d))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input is not a double.");
    }
}
```